# knockoutjs $index is not working in mapping plungin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using asp.net mvc 3 and knockoutjs 2.0 and mapping plugin
I have converted my model as json as below using mapping plugin

```
viewModel=ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Html.Serialize(Model)));

<div class="orders">
        <div data-bind="foreach: JobOrder">
            <div data-bind="text:$index">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

my model is

```
 public class Jobs : EntityBase
    {

        [MLLAttr(ObjectType = MLLObjectType.Child, IsCreate = true, ParentName = "Jobs", IsRequired = true)]
        public List<JobOrder> JobOrder { get; set; }
   }
```

$index is not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$index` was introduced in version 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael pointed out, `$index` was introduced in knockout 2.1. You will need to update to use it